# Boolean return value of scripts in booggie2

Tags: booggie

How is the Boolean return value of scripts (without explicit return value) defined? A rule always returns either TRUE or FALSE (depending if it was succesfully applied) which can be used to control your rule sequence. For scripts this currently doesn't work (at least in my applications).

Please note: The booggie-project does not exist anymore but led to the development of [Soley Studio](https://www.soley.io/en/pr-soley-studio/) which covers the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, scripts return a boolean value to the sequence. This is done using a `bool()`-cast.

Hence, if your script has no return value, it is internally interpreted as `bool(None)` which gives you `False`.

If your script has an explicitly defined return statement, the `bool()`-cast naturally return `True`.